# ORA-00979 Not a GROUP BY Expression with complex EXTRACTVALUE

Tags: oracle, xpath, group-by

I'm trying to execute a rather simple Oracle query against a table with a XMLTYPE column:

```
Select POB_CODPOL, CODSIS From (
    Select T1.POB_CODPOL, EXTRACTVALUE(T1.POB_XMLPOL, '/Polbas/polfun[nomfun="filterBySystem"]/extpar[codele="codsis"]/valele/text()') CODSIS 
    From TDTX_POLITICA_CLOB T1
    Where T1.POB_CODEMP = '001840' 
)     
Group By POB_CODPOL, CODSIS
```

This throws a `ORA-00979 Not a GROUP BY Expression`, which I don't really understand. 
Even worse: when I execute the exact same query, but with a simplified XPATH query **does** work:

```
Select POB_CODPOL, CODSIS From (
    Select T1.POB_CODPOL, EXTRACTVALUE(T1.POB_XMLPOL, 'Polbas/codpol/text()') CODSIS 
    From TDTX_POLITICA_CLOB T1
    Where T1.POB_CODEMP = '001840' 
)     
Group By POB_CODPOL, CODSIS
```

It looks like Oracle doesn't like conditions like `[nomfun="filterBySystem"]` when using a `GROUP BY` (without the grouping clause, everything works fine).

Any idea on why this can be happening?

**Edit**: the result of the inner query is rather simple:

[image]

Comment: What is the result of the inner query (without the group by) ?

Comment: It's a simple three character text. I've updated the question with more information. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when you cast it to a string, e.g. `CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(T1.POB_XMLPOL, 'Polbas/codpol/text()') AS VARHCAR2(100)`

Comment: Nope, already tried that. Doesn't work with CAST, nor with stuff like TO_CHAR.

Comment: `EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated. Does it work better with `XMLTABLE`, similar to `SELECT T1.POB_CODPOL, x.CODSIS 
FROM TDTX_POLITICA_CLOB T1
 NATURAL JOIN XMLTABLE('/Polbas/polfun[nomfun="filterBySystem"]/extpar[codele="codsis"]/valele' PASSING POB_XMLPOL COLUMNS
  CODSIS VARCHAR2(50) PATH '/') x`

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried, it looks like this works! If you post an answer, I'll validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated.

Oracle recommends to use [XMLQUERY](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm#SQLRF00640), [XMLTABLE](http://resp%20docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232) for it.

This one should work:

```
WITH t as
    (SELECT T1.POB_CODPOL, x.CODSIS 
     FROM TDTX_POLITICA_CLOB T1 
          NATURAL JOIN XMLTABLE('/Polbas/polfun[nomfun="filterBySystem"]/extpar[codele="codsis"]/valele‌​' 
             PASSING POB_XMLPOL COLUMNS 
             CODSIS VARCHAR2(50) PATH '/') x
     Where T1.POB_CODEMP = '001840')
SELECT POB_CODPOL, CODSIS 
FROM t
GROUP BY POB_CODPOL, CODSIS;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a Bug 28588011 : "ORA-00979: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION" WHEN TABLE FORMAT IS BINARY XML.

```
Severity    2 - Severe Loss of Service
Created 02-Sep-2018
Status  11 - Code/Hardware Bug (Response/Resolution)
WORKAROUND No
```

I guess they won't fix it. But the hint *NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE* (that I use for other XML related bugs, too) worked for me.