# How to use Order by,Group by , Count() etc. operation on table having XMLType column?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsqldeveloper

My table data look like this..

```
 <OneAirport>
     <Rank>3</Rank>
     <Airport>Dubai International</Airport>
     <Location>Garhoud</Location>
     <Country>United Arab Emirates</Country>
      <Code_IATA>DXB</Code_IATA>
      <Code_ICAO>OMDB</Code_ICAO>
      <Total_passenger>88242099</Total_passenger>
     <Rank_change>0</Rank_change>
     <Percent_Change>5.5</Percent_Change>
 </OneAirport>
```

I am trying to use SQL clauses like order by, group by on XmlElements(tags) but getting error...
Is there any way i can sort this data tag vise?

My Code:

```
 select extract(airport, '/')"airports2017XML" from AIRPORTS2017XML
 order by EXTRACTVALUE(airport,'/OneAirport/Country') ASC ;
```

My Output:

Excluding the 1st two rows, rest of the output is correct .I don't know why these 2 rows are not sorted ??

[image]

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you need ... please post what you tried and whats the expectation

Comment: I tried using extract(),extractvalue() along with order by and group by but got error.I am looking to sort my xml data in table based on specific tags. Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried this ...just refer and see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824304/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression-with-complex-extractvalue

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reference.